# Want to know the meaning of this operator ?. in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to know the meaning of ?. operator in dart , if any one can explain it ? , thank you  .
for example :
final length=names?.length;

Comment: You may find it helpful to read the documentation on null safety: https://dart.dev/null-safety

Comment: thank u so much for your help .

Answer (score 0):

That means that you are accessing a property that may be null. When you declare a variable but never set it, you do this:

```
String? testString; // the ? operator means that the variable can be null
```

This was added to prevent your program from crashing by null pointer exceptions.

I suggest you read Michael Horns comment which includes the documentation for null safety in Dart.

Comment: thank u so much bro , i found this answer too  = > when you use blocks?.first, the value of blocks can be null, but when you use blocks!.first, you inform the compiler that you are certain that blocks are not null.

final block = blocks!.first; means you are completely assured that List<Block>? blocks is initialized before block assignment.

also in final block = blocks?.first;, block will be nullable, but in final block = blocks!.first;, block is not nullable.

Answer (score 0):

? is a nullable operator, meaning the variable you are accessing may be null.

An example below shows how you can perform operation on nullable variable:

```
String? data;
final bool hasData = (data ?? '').isNotEmpty;

bool? isCalled;
final bool isItReallyCalled = isCalled == true;
```

This way, you do not need to check if the variable is null or use the ! operator, which may cause null pointer exceptions.

Comment: Thank you so much bro for your help ♥️